# Making alternative names for expl3 commands

Tags: macros

I am making some style files where I use underscores in the command names.  At the end of the package, I want to make equivalent commands for users.  How can I add an additional name for `\piston_alumin_pg` to be `\wvAluminPg` ?  How about commands made by `\newtheorem` and `\newenvironment` ?

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

\RequirePackage{geometry}

\newcommand{\piston_alumin_pg}
  { \geometry{ paperwidth=13cm, paperheight=21cm,
               textwidth=12cm,  textheight=20cm,
               left=8mm, right=8mm, top=8mm, bottom=8mm} }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: environments generated by newtheorem and newenvironment are document level constructs so should  not have `_` in their names so the problem does not arise.

Comment: Do you write .sty-files to be used by others while not knowing about basics in TeX programming?

Comment: The others know even less !

Comment: I know how to build software.  I don't like its design even though I intend to program with it.  That's all.

Comment: @Veak I fail to see how you can like or dislike its design without knowing what that design is.

Comment: `\piston_alumin_pg` is not a expl3 command. You haven't understand the design if you think that it is enough to add a few underscores.

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty odd style to do

```
\newcommand{\piston_alumin_pg}
```

although it works.

It would be far more idiomatic to define expl3 names using expl3 definitions, also an expl3 function should have `:`

so

```
\RequirePackage{geometry}

\ExplSyntaxOn


\cs_new_protected:Nn\piston_alumin_pg:
  { \geometry{ paperwidth=13cm, paperheight=21cm,
               textwidth=12cm,  textheight=20cm,
               left=8mm, right=8mm, top=8mm, bottom=8mm} }

\NewDocumentCommand\wvAluminPg{}
    {\piston_alumin_pg:}

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: `\cs_new_protected:Nn` and `\cs_set_eq:NN` and a trailing colon is missing in the first line.

Comment: @egreg I decided against set_eq (although that was my first thought) as I think a reasonable approach is only using expl3 definitions for expl3 csnames

Comment: I heartily disagree about `\let`. I can agree about `\NewDocumentCommand`.

Comment: Why do you opt on `\NewDocumentCommand` instead of `\newcommand` ?

Comment: because that was always the intended interface for declaring document interfaces to commands defined at the L3 layer. @Veak  `\newcommand` would also work but is in the 2e tradition. (actually 2.09 tradition as it predates 2e)

Comment: Thank you for the detail.  L3 Layer is the De Facto way even though you do not seem to promote it very much among users.

Comment: The website states there is no separate LaTeX3 format.  But there is actually.

Comment: If you are going to have a single format, what will you be calling it ?

Comment: I meant the name of the one after you complete the transition after you modernise.

Comment: latex2e with expl3 ?

Comment: For some reason I associated expl3 with Latex3.

Comment: @Vea As you clearly have already read, there will be no latex3 format.

Comment: If you were to use `set_eq` wouldn't `new_eq` be safer?

Comment: @cfr yes, it would